# Match particular values with specific color in colorkey levelplot R

Tags: r, maps, raster, r-raster, levelplot

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
```

I would like to make a custom colorkey for my map. My data spans both negative and positive values. Here is what I have tried to do:

```
    myat = unique(c(seq( -0.1497458,0,length=6),seq(0,0.1665365,length=6)))
        themes<- colorRampPalette((c("darkred", "red3","red","orange", "yellow","yellow4")))#(length(myat)-1)

myColorkey <- list(at=myat,space = "bottom",labels=list(cex=1,font=1,at=myat),height=1,width=1)
if (dev.cur() == 1) x11(width=4,height=4)

#s <- stack(Precip_DJF,Precip_DJFsim)
levelplot(Precip_DJFtmindiff, layout=c(1, 1), col.regions=themes, 
          colorkey=myColorkey,margin=FALSE,xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,par.strip.text=list(cex=0),scales=list(x=list(draw=FALSE),y=list(draw=FALSE)))
```

Results:
[image]

Question: How can I match the value 0 to yellow color and then place colorkey labels at midpoints of breaks instead of edges? I need cuts=10.

Thanks,
AT.

[reproducible example here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jib7fw9h1ucwvcm/raster.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this book](http://oscarperpinan.github.io/spacetime-vis/) I provide [an example](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/spacetime-vis/blob/master/raster.R#L97) to solve this question. My answer is mostly a copy of part of that example.

Because you don't provide a dataset to reproduce your code I will use the file proposed in the book:

```
library(rasterVis)

setwd(tempdir())
myURL <-'https://github.com/oscarperpinan/spacetime-vis/raw/master/data/'
download.file(paste0(myURL,'SISav.grd'), 'SISav.grd', method = 'wget')
download.file(paste0(myURL,'SISav.gri'), 'SISav.gri', method = 'wget')

SISav <- raster('SISav')
```

Next lines define the diverging palette:

```
meanRad <- cellStats(SISav, 'mean')
SISav <- SISav - meanRad
## Modify the palette with your colors
divPal <- brewer.pal(n=9, 'PuOr')
divPal[5] <- "#FFFFFF"
divTheme <- rasterTheme(region=divPal)

rng <- range(SISav[])
## Number of desired intervals
nInt <- 15
## Increment corresponding to the range and nInt
inc0 <- diff(rng)/nInt
## Number of intervals from the negative extreme to zero
n0 <- floor(abs(rng[1])/inc0)
## Update the increment adding 1/2 to position zero in the center of an interval
inc <- abs(rng[1])/(n0 + 1/2)
## Number of intervals from zero to the positive extreme
n1 <- ceiling((rng[2]/inc - 1/2) + 1)
## Collection of breaks
breaks <- seq(rng[1], by=inc, length= n0 + 1 + n1)
## Midpoints computed with the median of each interval
idx <- findInterval(SISav[], breaks, rightmost.closed=TRUE)
mids <- tapply(SISav[], idx, median)
## Maximum of the absolute value both limits
mx <- max(abs(breaks))
## Interpolating function that maps colors with [0, 1]
## rgb(divRamp(0.5), maxColorValue=255) gives "#FFFFFF" (white)
break2pal <- function(x, mx, pal){
    ## x = mx gives y = 1
    ## x = 0 gives y = 0.5
    y <- 1/2*(x/mx + 1)
    rgb(pal(y), maxColorValue=255)
}
divRamp <- colorRamp(divPal)
## Diverging palette where white is associated with the interval
## containing the zero
pal <- break2pal(mids, mx, divRamp)
```

And finally `levelplot` displays the result:

```
levelplot(SISav, par.settings=rasterTheme(region=pal),
          at=breaks, contour=TRUE)
```

[image: levelplot]

Comment: Cool! to reproduce this, I had to add a `library(rasterVis)` after the download lines. It would be nice if this could be done much simpler.

Comment: @EdzerPebesma edited. Thanks. I agree, but I couldn't find a simpler way. Maybe I will integrate it in the `levelplot` code as an additional option.

Comment: the issue is that `at` and `region` are fed with two pieces of information that have to cohere. Maybe we could come with a new argument, like `diverge = 0` (`NA` as default?) to specify the midpoint for a diverging color ramp; add this to sp for uniform reuse by sp:image, spplot, raster, rasterVis:levelplot etc?

Comment: That would be perfect.

Comment: @OscarPerpiñán  the image looks very good. You solved part of the problem (specifying colors) but I understand from Edzer Pebesma's comments it is impossible at the moment to get the labels at the center of color breaks. Please use my data (see edited post) to execute your script. I triend running the script with your data but could not access the data.

Comment: @aez849 No, it's a different problem. The location of the labels can be tuned with `colorkey`. It is described in [this FAQ](http://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/FAQ.html#sec-1).